# how to change boolean values with timerEvent in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2, flash-cs5, flash-cs4

I had written this small code to change a boolean value for 0 to 1 and vice versa every second 
but it doesnt work.

The result is it always stays as 0. I must be making some stupid mistake. Please help. Thanks

```
  var booleanL:Number = 0;
            var myTimerL:Timer = new Timer(1000,60);
            myTimerL.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListenerL);
                function timerListenerL (e:TimerEvent):void{
                    if(booleanL == 0) {
                        booleanL = 1;
                    } else if(booleanL == 1) {
                        booleanL = 0;
                    }
                }
            myTimerL.start();
            trace(booleanL);
```

Comment: try to put your trace inside of the "timerListenerL" method

Comment: why don't you use a Boolean type ? and do booleanL = !booleanL in your timerListenerL function

Comment: hi @Binou thanks for your reply, that seems to be working , rather than 0 or 1 i am getting true or false which is fine too however..rather than it executing true or false every 1 second its executing it extremely fast like 30 times a second (i think around my framerate) that should not happen :S

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
You can try using the computer clock time to make a stopwatch. The boolean will update every time the clock's `end_time time` is [delay] seconds higher than `start_time`. Delay is set by this line: `delay = start_time.seconds + 2;` here gives +2 seconds delay as limit before update

Try it like this...

```
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.events.Event; //added this for enter frame events

    public class timer extends MovieClip 
    {
        public var booleanL:int = 0;

        public var start_time:Date = new Date;
        public var end_time:Date =  new Date;
        public var delay:int;

        public function timer() 
        {
               //var myTimerL:Timer = new Timer(1000, 5);
               //myTimerL.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListenerL);
               //myTimerL.start();

               timer_Reset();
        }

        function timerListenerL ():void //(event:TimerEvent):void
        {
              trace("Am updating Boolean...");
              if( 1 == booleanL) 
              { booleanL = 0; trace(booleanL); } 
              else if (0 == booleanL) 
              { booleanL = 1; trace(booleanL);}
        }

        //USE REAL TIME CLOCK VERSION

        public function timer_Reset():void 
        {
                start_time = new Date; //reset time to now..
                delay = start_time.seconds + 2; //two seconds test delay
                stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _update);
        }

        function _update (e:Event):void
        {
                //set end_time to now-time every frame, 
                //then check if end seconds are [+ delay] higher than start_time.seconds

                end_time = new Date(); //set to Now time

                if (end_time.seconds ==  delay)
                {
                  trace(end_time.hours + ":" + end_time.minutes + ":" + end_time.seconds);
                  stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _update);
                  timerListenerL (); //we update boolean  via this function
                  timer_Reset(); //we reset for next check via this function
                }
        }

}
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply but the problem is still the same as I mentioned above..the damn thing changes between 0 and 1 very fast rather than happening every 1 second or whatever time I put.

Comment: Did you fix it? If not I can only think that this would be caused by an `enterFrame` function somewhere in your code. In any case I've updated with a second solution: Check against device clock time if X seconds have elapsed then update boolean.